# TypeScript: field default overwrites value set while executing super constructor

Tags: typescript, oop

After painful debugging, I've come to conclusion that TypeScript compiler treats my code unfairly. Is that a feature or a bug?

Here's my code:

```
class BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    this.dynamicMethod();
  }
  dynamicMethod() {
  }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  a = 'default';
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('@constructor: a =', this.a);
  }
  dynamicMethod() {
    this.a = 'abc';
    console.log("@dynamicMethod a =", this.a);
  }
}

const c = new ChildClass();
```

When running it, it outputs this:

```
@dynamicMethod a = abc
@constructor: a = default
```

The `BaseClass` constructor nicely calls the overwritten `dynamicMethod()`, the field `a` is populated with a correct value, but then that value is blatantly overwritten with the field's default value. I went to check how the compiled code looks like:

```
// Some infrastructure code was trimmed off
var BaseClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function BaseClass() {
        this.dynamicMethod();
    }
    BaseClass.prototype.dynamicMethod = function () {
    };
    return BaseClass;
}());
var ChildClass = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(ChildClass, _super);
    function ChildClass() {
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this.a = 'default';
        console.log('@constructor: a =', _this.a);
        return _this;
    }
    ChildClass.prototype.dynamicMethod = function () {
        this.a = 'abc';
        console.log("@dynamicMethod a =", this.a);
    };
    return ChildClass;
}(BaseClass));
var c = new ChildClass();
```

The important thing to note here is that the line `_this.a = 'default';` follows immediately after the `super()`, the base class constructor is called. And, the valuable data in field `a` is overwritten.

Is this how it should be? I tried to fix this by avoiding giving that field the default value. TSLint will then complain with

```
TS2564: Property 'a' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

I tried to shut it up by putting something like `this.a = 'default';` **before** the `super()` call. But that results in this error:

```
TS17009: 'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class.
```

So, that's pretty sad. If I try to initialize the field before `super()` call, that is illegal (for obvious reasons), but if it is initialized in the class declaration, then the default value overwrites value that was already populated. Of course, I can move the `dynamicMethod()` call out from the base class constructor, and call it from the child class constructor. But that triggers quite a lot of changes in all kinds of other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there is nothing wrong here, the `super` call must be the first call in the `child` class constructor. So everything works as it should, and this has nothing to do with Typescript in particular.

Flow:

1. `child` constructor gets called.
2. `super()` is called (sets `this` to child instance)
3. `parent` constructor is executed.
4. `dynamic` method is called (with `this` set to child class) and `a` is set to `abc`
5. `child` constructor continues to run to completion and sets `a` to `default`

You can silence the Typescript compiler by declaring `a` with the exclamation point
`public a!:string` then the initialization of `a` is at your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this how it should be?

Yes. And it’s not TS specific behavior. It’s defined in ES spec (stage 3 proposal). [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_instance_fields)

Back to TS, the proper type should be `a: string | undefined` without initial value. I know, TS will complain about `this.a` is possibly undefined. But it’s legit from type system point of view. I don’t know better way either.

If you prefer trade-in type soundness for ergonomic, you can turn off `strictPropertyInitialization` compiler option, and keep the property type as `a: string`. [Ref](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization)